# Vim-like clipboard manager with multiple buffers

Tags: software-recommendation, copy-paste, text-editor, vi

I am looking to expand the capabilities of my clipboard.

I've grown attached to how vim does it; multiple discrete buffers you can 'yank' (copy) text into.  I also generally prefer to use the mouse as little as possible.  All of the clipboard managers I've seen are GUI-heavy; so one that lets me yank to and paste from buffers using only the keyboard is ideal.

I'm on macOS 10.14.6, and would prefer something that I can install through Homebrew.  Happy to consider paid software.

Comment: make a request to enhance copyclip https://support.fiplab.com/hc/en-us/requests/new